# what is difference between PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED vs PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

Could you please tell me the the difference between PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED vs PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED thread attributes with there usage or example.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in [man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setinheritsched.3.html):

- PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED
  Threads that are created using attr inherit scheduling
  attributes from the creating thread; the scheduling attributes
  in attr are ignored.
- PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED
  Threads that are created using attr take their scheduling
  attributes from the values specified by the attributes object.

So there is a function with pointer and int arguments:

```
pthread_attr_setinheritsched(pthread_attr_t *attr, int inheritsched)
```

and *int* decides on whether to use *pointer* as a source of my child-threads attributes or set my child-threads attributes the same as parent thread (my ones).

Comment: ... which one can rationalize in terms of `pthread_attr_t` not being required to be able to convey that information via the scheduling attributes themselves.  That is, there is no reserved value of the scheduling attributes that says "don't use me, actually".  That's conveyed via a separate attribute, instead.